# I need help Identifying this Dirt Jumper Frame

Tags: identify-this-bike, dirt-jumps

I just picked up this bicycle but the previous owner didnt know what brand it was. It is custom painted and all the components seem to be high-end with no stock components. Note the unique cutout behind the crank and near the rear dropout. [image]

Comment: Check with local police department and stolen bikes registry. High end parts, recently painted and previous owner does not know is a strong hint.

Comment: bike is not reported stolen, i checked with the police

Comment: Still raising all sorts of red flags even though you checked with local police.  No serious rider forgets every detail about their bike.   Try asking seller again?